# Token Mismatch when uploading big files using laravel file manager

Tags: laravel-5, tinymce, file-manager

I'm using Laravel5.1 and `tinyMCE` with [laravel file manager (unisharp)](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager) and I'm always getting this error when I'm uploading big files (e.g. 20MB and up). I've searched about it on internet but I didn't find something similar with my problem. Please see my code for your review.

*Code:*

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="file_path" id="file_path" class="form-control" value="{{ Request::old('file_path') }}" readonly>
    <a id="lfm" class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary" data-input="file_path">
        <i class="fa fa-file"></i> Choose file...
    </a>
</div>
```

*Script:*

```
<script>
    getTiny('{{ URL::to('/') }}', 'textarea'); // customized function for tinyMCE
    {!! \File::get(base_path('vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/public/js/lfm.js')) !!}
    var domain = "{{ URL::to('/') }}/laravel-filemanager";
    $('#lfm').filemanager('file', {prefix: domain});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a larger `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size). Or any corresponding configs of your server like NginX or Apache.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this? because I don't want to change my `php.ini` again and again, if I have other projects.